# How Can I merge these two Access Sql queries

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, select, insert

I want to merge these two queries into one query.
Here are the codes.
it's one table for both, but you see different data from different parts.
Just I want to make one record with only one query.

```
> DoCmd.RunSQL "insert into Report (id, [date], namep , [NEXTC],
> [Nurse])" & _ " values (" & Chr(34) & x & Chr(34) & " ," & Chr(34) & b
> & Chr(34) & "," & "5," & _ " " & Chr(34) & c & Chr(34) & ", " &
> Chr(34) & n & Chr(34) & ")"
```

and this one

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Report ( brand, Bag, Acc, Id , NameP)" & _
"Select Top 1 * from" & _
    "(SELECT TOP 1 Brand FROM (SELECT * FROM Report WHERE ID=" & _
    x & _
    ") WHERE Brand IS NOT NULL ORDER BY date DESC Union All SELECT top 1 null FROM report WHERE Brand IS NULL) AS Brand," & _
    "(SELECT TOP 1 Bag FROM (SELECT * FROM Report WHERE ID=" & _
    x & _
    ") WHERE Bag IS NOT NULL ORDER BY date DESC Union All SELECT top 1 null FROM report WHERE Bag IS NULL) AS Bag," & _
    "(SELECT TOP 1 ACC FROM (SELECT * FROM Report WHERE ID=" & _
    x & _
    ") WHERE ACC IS NOT NULL ORDER BY date DESC Union All SELECT top 1 null FROM report WHERE ACC IS NULL) AS ACC," & _
 "(SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Report WHERE ID=" & _
 x & _
 ") AS ID," & _
 "( SELECT TOP 1 NameP FROM Report WHERE ID=" & _
 x & _
 ") as NameP;"
```

Comment: It doesnt let me to somthing like this
`INSERT INTO Report  ( brand, Bag, Acc, Id)
Select Top 1 * from 
((SELECT TOP 1 Brand FROM (SELECT Brand,date FROM Report WHERE ID= x) WHERE Brand IS NOT NULL), '','',5022)`

Comment: Could you show some example data? Your query is beyond comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this, it should work (maybe some parentheses be wrong, check it before use):

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "insert into Report (id, [date], namep , [NEXTC], [Nurse], brand, Bag, Acc, Id , NameP)" & _
" values (" & Chr(34) & x & Chr(34) & " ," & Chr(34) & b & Chr(34) & "," & "5," & _
" " & Chr(34) & c & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & n & Chr(34) & ", " & _
"(SELECT TOP 1 Brand FROM (SELECT * FROM Report WHERE ID=" & x & _
") WHERE Brand IS NOT NULL ORDER BY date DESC Union All SELECT top 1 null FROM report WHERE Brand IS NULL) AS Brand " & ", " & _
"(SELECT TOP 1 Bag FROM (SELECT * FROM Report WHERE ID=" & x & _
") WHERE Bag IS NOT NULL ORDER BY date DESC Union All SELECT top 1 null FROM report WHERE Bag IS NULL) AS Bag " & ", " & _
"(SELECT TOP 1 ACC FROM (SELECT * FROM Report WHERE ID=" & x & _
") WHERE ACC IS NOT NULL ORDER BY date DESC Union All SELECT top 1 null FROM report WHERE ACC IS NULL) AS ACC " & ", " & _
"(SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Report WHERE ID=" & x & ") AS ID," & _
 "( SELECT TOP 1 NameP FROM Report WHERE ID=" & x & ") as NameP )"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not clear but your query should be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Report (id, [date], namep , [NEXTC], [Nurse], brand, Bag, Acc, Id , NameP)
SELECT TOP 1 'value1', 'value2', ..., FROM yourTable ...
```

Using [INSERT INTO SELECT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)

`value1`, `value2` could be statistic but also you can get some value from `yourtable`

Comment: it says this operation is not allowed in subqueries!

Comment: You should look into your query. You can use `INSERT INTO SELECT` if you want to `INSERT` from a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: I have used it if you check the second query it is insert with select

Comment: Is it possible to use variable in access sql query?

Comment: You can. `SELECT 'a', a FROM table`. first a is actual a but the 2nd a is coming from table

Comment: Sth like INSERT INTO Report ( Brand, NameP ,id)
values ((@brand), 5, 5022);
@Brand =INSERT INTO TempSelect ( Brand, NameP ,id)
values (("SELECT Brand,date FROM Report WHERE ID=5022) WHERE Brand IS NOT NULL ORDER BY date DESC Union All SELECT top 1 null FROM report WHERE Brand IS NULL"), 5, 5022);

Comment: "You know the both of them are working correctly.
I want to use second one then I bring date int it:
`INSERT INTO Report ( brand, Bag, Acc, Id , NameP, DATE)`
Now I can use select for brand and bag and ...
BUt I do want to set the date value from a variable"

Comment: In this part `Select Top 1 * from`, instead of using *, put the aliases you are getting from your subquery and for date, use the variable you have